# Apply Function on specific Elements in specific class

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm new at java script. I used this code to apply "press" function on two elements on "button" class

```
unsafeWindow.press = function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0].click();
    document.getElementsByClassName("button")[1].click(); 
}
```

Any way , It's just applied on the first (which is 0 in this case ) , 
Any Idea ?

This is The Html

```
<body>
<div class="questionBox" id="question_box_12289827274">
<div class="question" dir="ltr">
<span class="text-bold"><span dir="ltr">First question</span></span>
</div></div>
<div class="answer" dir="ltr">
first answer
</div>
<div class="likeBox">        
<span class="like-active" style="display:none"></span>
<div class=" ghostLink">
<a class="button"  href="#" onclick="Like.quickLike(12289827274, &quot;a_barsa&quot;, &quot;/likes/jack22/question/12289827274/add&quot;); return false;" style="display:block"></a>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="questionBox" id="question_box_12289827274">
<div class="question" dir="ltr">
<span class="text-bold"><span dir="ltr">second question</span></span>
</div></div>
<div class="answer" dir="ltr">
second answer
</div>
<div class="likeBox">        
<span class="like-active" style="display:none"></span>
<div class=" ghostLink">
<a class="button"  href="#" onclick="Like.quickLike(12289827786, &quot;a_barsa&quot;, &quot;/likes/jack22/question/12289827786/add&quot;); return false;" style="display:block"></a>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

This is javascript

```
body = document.body;
if(body != null) {
    div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute('id','like2');
    div.style.position = "fixed";
    div.style.display = "block";
    div.style.width = "25px"; 
    div.style.opacity= 0.90;
    div.style.bottom = "+40px";
    div.style.left = "+6px";
    div.style.right = "+6px";
    div.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
    div.style.border = "1px solid #94a3c4";
    div.style.padding = "2px";
    div.innerHTML = "<a onclick='OtomatisLike5()'><img src='http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/RcG/er5/RcGer5RcL.png' width='26' height='24' align='absmiddle' />&nbsp;&nbsp;5</a>"

    body.appendChild(div);

    unsafeWindow.OtomatisLike5 = function() {
        var clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
  });
document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0].dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
document.getElementsByClassName("button")[1].dispatchEvent(clickEvent);






        buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
        for(i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            myClass = buttons[i].getAttribute("class");
            if(myClass != null && myClass.indexOf("like") >= 0)
                if(buttons[i].getAttribute("name") == "likern false;")
                    buttons[i].click();
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: whether the page is refreshed on the click?

Comment: can you show the html? also, you are using `[2]` so it would be the third button, are you saying the 4th button isnt working? arrays are zero indexed

Comment: @atmd I know that 0 indexed , can you see the question after edit

Comment: @a_barsa show your html

Comment: you can try same with jQuery $(".button").on("click", function(){});

Comment: @KAG your code add event handler, but in question trigger this handler

Comment: yes, I see you want to trigger the click, you have already bound an event. have added an answer

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by atmd, arrays in javascript are zero indexed so you should reference 2 and 3 for 3rd and 4th elementes. Also you're running getElementsByClassName two times which is unnecessary.

Try this:

```
unsafeWindow.press = function(){
    var as = document.getElementsByClassName("a");
    as[2].click();
    as[3].click();
}
```

Also, getElementsByClassName will retrieve any html element whose attribute class equals "button", in your case. If you want to retrieve all button nodes in the page use getElementsByTagName instead.

Comment: in question problem not with index, but with only one hanlder work

Comment: Do you see any js errors? If the call to the first click doesn't work, the second won't get executed.

Answer (score 0):

To trigger an events on those elements you'd need to create an event object then dispatch it on the element:

```
 var clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
  });

document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0].dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
document.getElementsByClassName("button")[1].dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

if using jquery to bind events you'd use

```
$('.button').trigger('click');
```

if this is only working on one of your element and not the other, you'd need to look at how you are binding those events. Also note that jquery bound events can only be fired with jquery and natively bound events are triggered natively (as per the first method)

Comment: I tried "

 unsafeWindow.press = function() {
        var clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
  });

document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0].dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
document.getElementsByClassName("button")[1].dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
    "
But no thing happend at all , Can The HTML help ?
 @atmd

Comment: can you update the question to show how/where your javascript code is. Also, where are you calling the `unsafeWindow.press` function?

Comment: @atmd You may dispatch events like that but it is not mandatory if all he wants to do is invoke the function associated with the button's click event.

Comment: so you are creating element dynamically and injecting into the DOM then adding events to them, if that was mentioned in the original question you might have had better answers. where is that script? in the head, body tag?